# Possible to embed forge Viewer in Tableau dashboards?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is it possible to embed the forge viewer in Tableau dashboards? Or is there a reason why forge viewer has moslty been tested with Power bi?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I don't see any limitation to create an application that uses both Technologies if Tableau is your desired service for Dashboards. It will be a matter of looking into what you could embed. In the Tableau developer tools I see a section for Embedded Analytics - https://www.tableau.com/developer/tools This could give you a good start to look into it - https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_sample_basic_embed.htm